# facebook: why are users not notified when they are invited to an event via API?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I am inviting users to my event via Graph API:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/

Unfortunately the users don't get a notification. The event shows up in their event list though.

Any ideas why no notification is generated?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that when you invite a user using the api like that then the notification the user gets is through the bookmarks count for *Events*.

Also, it's nice of you to link to the documentation, but it's not very helpful to understand your problem... It would have been more helpful to just include the code you are using.

Answer (score 0):

They are notified in their news feed, but they are not invited.

Comment: I was having a similar issue with creating group events and not being able to invite the entire group. Here is my solution for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19676654/creating-and-inviting-a-group-to-an-event-via-graph-api